# Running into a problem starting up mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I downloaded MongoDB with Compass and the shell as accessories and started learning from W3Schools Node.js MongoDB section.
Step 1: type into command prompt>npm install mongodb
success
step 2: create a MongoClient object file with this code and then save

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Step 3: Once the code above is saved run the file by calling it on the command prompt
C:\Users\MyName>node fileName.js

and this is the response I'm getting

```
C:\Users\*****\MongoDB Tutorials>node demo_create_mongo_db.js
C:\Users\*****\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:418
                    throw error;
                    ^

MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\*****\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:293:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:557:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:500:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) {
      'localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        _hostAddress: HostAddress { isIPv6: false, host: 'localhost', port: 27017 },
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 11442648,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (C:\Users\*****\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:379:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\*****\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connect.js:302:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:510:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
        }
      }
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v17.2.0
```

What do I do about this?

Comment: MongoDB must first be running.  Can you verify you can connect to the mongodb using a mongodb shell?  If so, then you should be able to connect using NodeJS.

Comment: If you are unfamiliar how to detect if mongo is running, or how to connect using the shell please let me know

Comment: According to my task manager, its running.

Comment: And yes I can access the shell just by typing in mongosh into my command prompt